# Using bash to split lines into train and validation set

Tags: bash, awk

I have writtin following bash script to split the input file into two for following signature:
splitfiles filename 0.9
where 0.9 is the training set proportion and rest is testset.

```
function splitfiles()
{
length=$(wc -l $1)
top=$(($length*$2))
head -n $top $1 >traintxt
tail -n $(($length-$top)) $1 >valtxt

}
```

but it throws following error for file  110-1.txt

$splitfiles 110-1.txt 0.9

bash: 4756073 110-1.txt*0.9: syntax error in expression (error token is "110-1.txt*0.9")

Comment: How is this function getting called?

Comment: splitfiles 110-1.txt 0.9 @anubhava

Comment: BASH arithmetic doesn't do floating point.

Comment: so how to do that? @anubhava

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split the files randomly you can use another awk one liner to use awk's rand() function to split the files probabilistically:

```
awk '{if(rand()<0.9) {print > output.train} else {print > output.test}}' input
```

If you need to parameterise the filenames this it is a bit more complicated, as you then need to pass them to awk using the -v switch:

```
in="myLibSVMdata"
train="$in.train"
test="$in.test"
awk -v train="$train" -v test="$test" '{if(rand()<0.9) {print > train} else {print > test}}' $in
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
wc -l $1
```

by

```
wc -l < $1
```

to avoid filename in output.

Comment: so please also mention how to do it

Comment: With current GNU bash and bc: `top=$(bc -l <<< "$length*$2")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command to replace your `splitfiles` function:

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < "$1") -v fact="$2" 'NR <= lines * fact {
              print > "traintxt"; next} {print > "valtxt"}' "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a slight improvement to @Rob Challen's answer: I made it into a function, where the ratio is also controllable and where we are sure the train and test/dev files are created and can be appended to.

```
function split_train_val(){
in=$1
train=$2
test=$3
ratio=$4

echo "" > $train
echo "" > $test
awk -v train="$train" -v test="$test" '{if(rand()<$ratop) {print > train} else {print > test}}' $in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case @Rob Challen's answer does not work for you, try this:

```
awk '{if(rand()<0.9) {print $0 > "output.train"} else {print $0 > "output.test"}}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a commonly used operation in Data Science and Machine Learning projects. I ended up writing a utility for it. Hope you find it useful !

```
function split() {
    filepath=$1;
    filepath_train=$2;
    filepath_valid=$3;
    filepath_test=$4;
    num_lines=$(wc -l $filepath | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d' ' -f1);
    line_nr_train_end=$(($num_lines * 4/5))
    line_nr_valid_end=$(($num_lines * 4/5 + 1 + $num_lines * 1/10))
    cat $filepath | awk -v line_nr_train_end=$line_nr_train_end 'NR <= line_nr_train_end' > $filepath_train;
    cat $filepath | awk -v line_nr_train_end=$line_nr_train_end -v line_nr_valid_end=$line_nr_valid_end 'NR > line_nr_train_end && NR <= line_nr_valid_end' > $filepath_valid;
    cat $filepath | awk -v line_nr_valid_end=$line_nr_valid_end 'NR > line_nr_valid_end' > $filepath_test;
```

}

You call the method as

```
split filetosplit.txt train.txt valid.txt test.txt
```